# Is the Go HTTP handler goroutine expected to exit immediately in this case?

Tags: http, go, cancellation

I have one Go HTTP handler like this:

```
mux.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    defer cancel()

    if cn, ok := w.(http.CloseNotifier); ok {
        go func(done <-chan struct{}, closed <-chan bool) {
            select {
            case <-done:
            case <-closed:
                fmt.Println("client cancelled....................!!!!!!!!!")
                cancel()
            }
        }(ctx.Done(), cn.CloseNotify())
    }

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("I am still running...........")

    fmt.Fprint(w, "cancellation testing......")
})
```

The API works fine, then with curl before the request finish I terminate the curl command deliberately with `Control-C`, and on server side I do see the `client cancelled....................!!!!!!!!!` get logged out, but after a while the `I am still running...........` get logged out also, I thought this goroutine will be terminated immediately!

So, is this desired behaviour, or I did something wrong?

If it is expected, since whatever the goroutine will complete its work, then what is the point of the early cancellation?

If I did something wrong, please help to point me out the correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a [`contex.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) that can be cancelled, which you do cancel when the client closes the connection, BUT you do not check the context and your handler does nothing differently if it is cancelled. The context only *carries* timeout and cancellation signals, it does not have the power nor the intent to kill / terminate goroutines. The goroutines themselves have to monitor such cancellation signals and act upon it.

So what you see is the expected output of your code.

What you want is to monitor the context, and if it is cancelled, return "immediately" from the handler.

Of course if you're "sleeping", you can't monitor the context meanwhile. So instead use [`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After), like in this example:

```
mux.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    if cn, ok := w.(http.CloseNotifier); ok {
        go func(done <-chan struct{}, closed <-chan bool) {
            select {
            case <-done:
            case <-closed:
                fmt.Println("client cancelled....................!!!!!!!!!")
                cancel()
            }
        }(ctx.Done(), cn.CloseNotify())
    }

    select {
    case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("5 seconds elapsed, client didn't close")
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Context closed, client closed connection?")
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, "cancellation testing......")
})
```

Comment: oh, i see, so if i start new goroutines here, and maybe those goroutines will also start new ones, so for all the downstream goroutines i need to manually monitor the context? i thought somehow the context package will help me to terminate those goroutines immediately!

Comment: @lnshi The context only _carries_ timeout and cancellation info, it does not have power to kill / terminate goroutines. The goroutines themselves have to monitor such cancellation signal and act upon it.

Comment: sorry, after monitored the cancellation i found i still don't know what exactly should to to terminate the handler, i added piece of my think here: https://play.golang.org/p/7xjjiW7XdoQ can u help to point me out the correct way? basically i want to achieve that when client close the connection, my server just immediately terminate the handler, release the resources, don't do any remained work, and just quit unconditionally.

Comment: @lnshi If cancellation is detected, you have to return from the handler. That signals the web server that serving that request ended. Depending on what your handler does, it must monitor (at least occasionally) the channel for cancellation, and it must terminate and return. This is your task to do, this won't happen automatically.

Comment: So use the approach that put the real work on a for select case branch and send it with a one time signal to notify it to start? Just feel wried

Comment: @lnshi If the task can be broken down to small pieces, use a loop, each iteration does a small piece and also checks the cancellation signal. If cancelled, return. If not, continue with the next iteration. If a loop is not practical, just insert a check once in a while in the series of statements that realizes the job. Use common sense and logic.